# Sorting a new column on task list on open atrium

Tags: distributions

Hey I have added two new column's to a task list. One is a Due Date (Date chosen by calendar) and the second is number of days out (integers). The other column's that are added by default are able to be sorted, however the two new columns only have a black title.

Is there a way to add the ability to sort these new columns?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

1. Go to adminstration/structure/views/
2. Click Edit for Open Atrium Worktracker
3. In Filter Criteria click add, then select column of choice
4. Click the "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"